# Can we declare an object of a class inside a function of the same class in C++?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

I have to declare a an object of a class inside function of the same class but I am not sure if that is possible and I can't execute my program and check because it is not ready.

I have to use the object for several different tasks inside the function.

Comment: Yes. You should add information in your question including your current [mcve], as well as what you're trying to do and why you can't execute your program (e.g. does it not compile, or crash while running)

Comment: Program is not ready yet so it can't be executed.

Comment: The sample problem is. I have a class "Train" it has a Member Function "addtrain()". I wanted to know if I can declare an object of "Train" inside "addtrain ()"?

Comment: yes you can. But it would be easier to understand your problem, when we can see your code. So please edit your post and paste it here

Comment: You should not write a lot of code without testing it. Except when one make massive changes in large existing code base, you should be able to fix problem that prevent your code to execute in a few minute. If not, then you are probably trying to write too much code at once. **Also, for a question like that, one can create a program to test it is less than 2 minutes anyway**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate, modify and return an object of the same class within a member function, no matter if static or not. Here is some nonsensical but working code that shows you some possibilities.

```
class Train {
public:
    int a;

    Train(int a) : a(a) {}

    static Train addTrain() {
        Train t = Train(4);
        t.a = 2;
        return t;
    }

    void add(int num) {
        Train t = Train(num);
        this->a += t.a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, it was certainly very helpful